# Application status in hadoop cluster manager is undefined

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I am trying to run a HelloWorld programing in Pig or Hive on my single-cluster setup. All my applications hangs. That includes my word count example in pig. My Hive command below also hangs:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM u_data;

My Hive logs stops as follows: set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1433035285759_0006, Tracking URL = http://der-Inspiron-3521:8088/proxy/application_1433035285759_0006/
Kill Command = /home/der/utility/hadoop-2.7.0/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1433035285759_0006
```

I follow the link. The application shows the

```
status = undefined
```

Here's my map-reduce configuration file:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
<property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
  <value>localhost:10020</value>
  <description>Host and port for Job History Server (default 0.0.0.0:10020)</description>
</property>

  <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address</name>
  <value>localhost:50030</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

My hadoop server is version 2.7.0.
I tried hadoop server 2.6.0 but I had other issues.

My pig scripts hangs at the MapReduce Launching stage:

```
     2015-05-30 19:34:59,641 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.
    mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 
detailed locations: M: lines[1,8],words[-1,-1],
wordcount[4,12],grouped[3,10] C: wordcount[4,12],grouped[3,10] R: wordcount[4,12]
        2015-05-30 19:34:59,666 [main] 
INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.
hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer
    MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete
        2015-05-30 19:34:59,666 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.
    mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 
Running jobs are [job_1433039621140_0001]
```